# how to set background color to IKImageBrowserView

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, ikimagebrowserview

I am new to cocoa..
 I am creating one of the colorful window. so I need set background color to `IKImageBrowserView`.  I think subclassing `IKImageBrowserView` is the way to set background color but it is too difficult for me..
Any other way to set background color without subclassing?

Comment: down voters tell the reason for down vote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve what You want by using `setValue:forKey` with option key `IKImageBrowserBackgroundColorKey` like this:

```
[imageBrowserViewOutlet setValue:[NSColor redColor] forKey:IKImageBrowserBackgroundColorKey];
```

**Note:** *imageBrowserViewOutlet* is `IKImageBrowserView` outlet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using:

```
[thumbnailBrowser setValue:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.125f green:0.145f blue:0.145f alpha:1.0f]   forKey:IKImageBrowserBackgroundColorKey];
```

Change RGB as you like. thumbnailBrowser is IKImageBrowserView. Gook luck!